# What List implementation does Spring's core.JdbcTemplate.query return?

Tags: java, spring

More specifically for `public <T> List<T> query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper) throws DataAccessException`

I tried following through the source listing but it just gives me a bunch of data extractors and jdbc calls, with nowhere where it explicitly creates a `List`-subtype implementation. I'm curious because I want to find out how Spring manages to instantiate a `List`, or if it 'cheats' by returning a sub-implementation like in `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: Just call `.getClass()` on the returned value. It doesn't instantiate `List`.

Comment: It could just be creating a `new ArrayList<>()` or a `new LinkedList<>()`, like you would do in your method. But why should you care about that? Those are implementation details, and can be changed at any point of time

Comment: You should not care about the returned `List` implementation.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes I know, I was simply curious :). Although it seems that most methods which advertise a `List<T>` simply just return an `ArrayList<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JdbcTemplate#query(String, RowMapper)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#JdbcTemplate) invokes the overloaded [`JdbcTemplate#query(String, ResultSetExtractor)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#JdbcTemplate.query%28java.lang.String%2Corg.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor%29) by providing a [`RowMapperResultSetExtractor`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java#RowMapperResultSetExtractor) as an argument.

Its implementation of [`extractData`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java#RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData%28java.sql.ResultSet%29) creates a `java.util.ArrayList`.